# Can't get an authorized user in integration test with Rails 3.1/Authlogic/ActiveRecord session store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, authlogic, session-store

I am trying to write a simple integration test on a Rails 3.1 application that uses Authlogic and ActiveRecord SessionStore, but I'm hitting the wall.

First, I tried a classic approach: after ensuring that `require "authlogic/test_case"` line is already in our `test_helper.rb` I then wrote a setup method that calls `activate_authlogic` and then uses `UserSession(@user)` to create a session.

This did create a session (as proved by `UserSession.find`), but when doing a `get` request on protected resource, the response would be a redirect to the login form and session was killed (ie. `UserSession.find` would return `nil`)

I tried POST-ing the email/password as well, but that seems to work **only** if I change the session store back to cookie_store (something I found out from [this comment](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/rails/get-session-in-rails-integration-test/#comment-8974)).

Switching session store to `CookieStore` just for test would be an option, but there are some tests that already depend on ActiveRecord store.

Is there any way to switch the session store just for one test? Is there any other solution to this problem that I'm missing?

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProtectedTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    activate_authlogic
    @user = Factory(:user, :roles => 'user')
    UserSession.create(@user)
  end

  def test_protected
    https!
    get '/protected'
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dear people from the future:](http://xkcd.com/979/)

I figured a workaround to this by starting tests that needed authorized users in a different environment by setting ENV["RAILS_ENV"] before including 'test_helper'. Then I changed `session_store` in that environment to cookie_store.

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test_cs"
require 'test_helper'
end

class ProtectedTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
  # ...
end
```